# User folder not showing up in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-server-2003, directory, windows-explorer

I have a user that logs into the domain receiving an error message regarding their "my documents" folder being inaccessible. Browsing the D:\Users directory using Windows Explorer on the server, the user's folder does not show up in the list (showing hidden and system files is enabled). However, using a command prompt, the users folder DOES show up in a DIR command list. I can also type the path (D:\Users\username) in the address bar in Windows Explorer and see the contents of the folder. But when I click to go up one level in the folder tree structure, it correctly goes up to the D:\Users directory but the folder isn't listed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Copy folder contents to new folder.  Delete old folder.  Rename new folder.  Call it a day.

Comment: 1. I'm assuming (even though you didn't state it) that you're using Folder Redirection to redirect the user's My Documents folder to a share on the server. 2. Is Access Based Enumeration enabled on the share? 3. Are you letting Windows create the user's folder?

Comment: @HopelessN00b You're definitely right on the money, but where's the fun in that? I guess I have a need to know why something's the way it is and how it got that way. THe mystery is calling me... heheh

Comment: @joeqwerty The user account was created a long time ago using Active Directory where a home directory is specified and created automatically. I believe the problem was caused by the business owner (that has admin access) copying the shared folder to another location. I should probably just chalk it up to that (since I'll never know exactly what he actually did) and follow HopelessN00b's suggestion. ABE looks interesting!

Comment: @HighTechGeek  Well, do what you wanna do, but take it from me, finding a corrupted ACL isn't really that fun or satisfying, especially after considering how much time and effort it took you to figure out what you already knew (the permissions are messed up), and realizing you could have fixed it in a few seconds of work instead.  Or, so my experience goes, at least.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I knew that I could do that, but I'm a sucker for solving puzzles... Anyway, I thought about it for another minute and just took your advice. I'm done with it now, so thanks. How do I credit a comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: @HighTechGeek  You can't.  Just post it as the answer and accept your own answer.  That's allowed here.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Don't you want the credit (even if it is a somewhat simple question)?

Comment: @HighTechGeek  Nah, it's fine.  Take the credit yourself, makes no difference to me.

Answer (score 1):

HopelessN00b pointed out the easiest solution: Copy folder contents to new folder. Delete old folder. Rename new folder. Call it a day.

I actually created a new folder and moved the files from the old folder. Interestingly enough, after moving the contents out of the old folder, the old folder showed up correctly in Windows Explorer, albeit as an empty folder. I deleted it anyway and renamed the new folder, shared it and tested user connectivity. All is good.